# No space between "bounty" and the username in bounty notices

Tags: bug, design, bounties, display-names, post-notices

This might be the smallest bug, however, it is irritating to see the username is connected to "bounty" with a period. There have been times when I think that could be a particular syntax on the Stack Exchange network for a moment.

[image: Math question 4605602. No space before the username]

The bounty notice above will be seen for six days [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4605602/580448). Or you can click the image above.

It looks like this bug happens across all question-answer sites.